# why is my minute hand and hour hand not showing up during execution with css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, real-time-clock

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelecetor('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) * 6) + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;
  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins / 60) * 30) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;

}
setInterval(setDate, 1000);
setDate();
```

```css
.hand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  transition: all 0.05s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the hour and the minute hand isnt showing up when i execute this code. only one hand shows up in the web page. the transform property to rotate it (120 degrees) isnt working(from the centre/pivot point)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelecetor is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you mistyped "querySelector".
You typed:

```
const minsHand = document.querySelecetor('.min-hand');
```